# How to Dynamically change the email template of workflow attached to content type

Tags: designer-workflow, content-type, sharepoint-email

I have a workflow attached to a content type. The main purpose of the workflow is to send email to the users. The content type was attached to so many lists in the Site. Now for one specific list i need to change the Template for the email. Is it was possible to change the  email template for the content type for specific lsits. can anyone suggest the best approach to meet the requirement. The workflow was designer workflow.
I am using 2010 workflow template in SharePoint 2013 designer

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible. Because workflow associate with Content type which is at site level.

So, My suggestion is create on Config List and put your email body inside it.

Using key/value pair in Config list, You can get different body for one list and for all other list get same email body.